# Combine sprite animation with path movement with CALayer

Tags: animation, path, xamarin.ios

In Monotouch, I need to create a basic animation of an image moving along a path while animating it's image content with a sprite sheet or replacing the content CGImage, everything i try i can't combine both animations. I tried subclassing the CALayer and animate custom properties or combine animations in group nothing seems to work. What's the best way to produce this kind of animation?

Answer (score 0):

To get a smooth animation, you want to think of what CAlayers represent: they are a handle to a texture that live in the GPU space.   To get smooth animation you can control a few of their properties, but arbitrary changes like rendering the data again wont work fine.

What you should do is put all of your images in the sprite sheet, and then animate  the ContentsRect property of the CALayer.